# WhatsApp backup to Google Drive

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I am planning to switch to a new phone. so on the old phone, I start WhatsApp backup to Google drive and I waited until it was completed. then I wanted to make sure that it is completed so I started the backup again and it showed me that it has some data and started uploading again.

I am now confused. are my chats backed up or not?

Answer (score 1):

Well, even I have encountered such a weird problem. But no worries, your chats are already backed up. For further confirmation, visit your Google Drive account and go to the Backups section. You should see a backup listed, namely, WhatsApp Backup , along with the time when the backup was completed. Each time you do a new backup, the time gets renewed.

If such a backup isn't listed, then perform the backup again. If it is, you can conveniently proceed.

Answer (score 1):

Every time you do a new backup, it will be uploaded to the Google Drive cloud. So, that's a cycle you'll forever keep on seeing. If one backup is complete, then you can switch to your new device.
Just in case something goes wrong, the data will remain on your old device and you can re-login there using the SMS OTP. Once you're satisfied that all data is restored on the new device, you can wipe your old device.